# Preserve key/values for autocomplete after deep merge in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, config, jsdoc, deep-copy

I'm writing a rather minimalistic config system. The idea is having a `config.template.js` and a `config.custom.js`. Now, all set values from *custom* should override those in *template*. Values missing from *custom* will be read from *template*.

The logic for that looks something like this:

```js
const isObject = item => item && typeof item === "object" && !Array.isArray(item);

const deepMerge = function(target, source){
    if (isObject(target) && isObject(source)){
        for (const key in source){
            if (isObject(source[key])){
                if (!target[key]) target[key] = {};
                deepMerge(target[key], source[key]);
            }
            else target[key] = source[key];
        }
    }
    return target;
};

// ...

const configCustom = (await import("./config.custom.js")).default;
const configBase = (await import("./config.template.js")).default;

export const config = {
    ...deepMerge(configBase, configCustom),
};
```

#### Now my problem:

VSCode doesn't know anything about how the resulting config actually looks like. So no autocomplete or types for keys.

VSCode *would* be able to provide autocomplete if I'd just do:

```js
export const config = {
    ...configBase,
    ...configCustom,
};
```

This however results in a shallow copy for nested keys, effectively overriding entire objects/arrays with, well, nothing.

Since I already make heavy use of JSDoc, I thought I could annotate the `deepMerge` function like

```js
/**
 * @param {object} target
 * @param {object} source
 * @return {import("./config.template.js").default}
 */
```

but that, of course, was wishful thinking and does not work.

#### So my question:

How can I provide autocomplete / types for this config system without relying on shallow copies?

---

<sub>I know that there are a ton of config systems and this is kinda re-inventing the wheel. I still want to understand and learn. 

And yes, TypeScript would make this easier.</sub>

---

### UPDATE:

[@creepsore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11303362/creepsore)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76530039/7575111) worked perfectly well. However I had to change a couple of annotations because I got some overloading errors 
(raised by VSCode with `"js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true`):

```js
/**
 * @template {object} T
 * @template {object} T2
 * @param {T} target
 * @param {T2 & Partial<T>} source
 * @returns {T & T2}
 */
const deepMerge = function(target, source){
    if (isObject(target) && isObject(source)){
        for (const key in source){
            if (isObject(source[key])){
                if (!target[key]) target[key] = {};
                deepMerge(target[key], source[key]);
            }
            else target[key] = source[key];
        }
    }
    return /** @type {T & T2} */ (target);
};

// ...

export const config = {
    ...deepMerge(
        configBase,
        /** @type {Partial<typeof configBase>} */ (configCustom),
    ),
};
```

Probably not the cleanest approach, but works perfectly well!

Comment: Couldn't you write a shallow config? So instead `{ opt1: { opt1_1: 'val', opt_1_2: 'val'}, opt2: 'val'}` you could go to `{'opt1.opt1_1': 'val', 'opt1.opt1_2': 'val', 'opt2': 'val'}`

Comment: @yunzen Unfortunately not. While the config system itself is pretty basic, the individual configs are nested

Comment: I reckoned that the nesting was your issue with the shallow copy. That's why I suggested that you use the names of the keys as nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when you define the two parameters of deepMerge as generics and use these as it's return type as such:

```
const isObject = item => item && typeof item === "object" && !Array.isArray(item);

/**
 * @template T
 * @template T2
 * @param {T} target 
 * @param {T2} source 
 * @returns {T&T2}
 */
const deepMerge = function(target, source){
    if (isObject(target) && isObject(source)){
        for (const key in source){
            if (isObject(source[key])){
                if (!target[key]) target[key] = {};
                deepMerge(target[key], source[key]);
            }
            else target[key] = source[key];
        }
    }
    return target;
};

const configCustom = (await import("./config.custom.js")).default;
const configBase = (await import("./config.template.js")).default;

export const config = {
    ...deepMerge(configBase, configCustom),
};
```

[image: Example]

These are my example configs i used for testing:

```
// config.template.js
export default {
    a: 420,
    b: 1337,
    c: 360
};

// config.custom.js
export default {
    b: 420
};
```